# How to go to a new page with selectedItem in Picker In Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a Picker in Xamarin and I want to go to the page which is selected in Picker. So here is my view in Picker:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Margin="20">
            <Label Text="List of tables" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Picker Title="Select table" ItemsSource="{Binding TablesFromViewModelCollector}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTable}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding SelectedTable.Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}"/>
            <Button Text="Select Table" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" Clicked="Selected_Button"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is it's contoller:

```
public TablePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new TableViewModel();
        }

        async void Selected_Button(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TableDetails());
        }
```

And here is TableViewModel where I can select the table from Picker:

```
class TableViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public IList<Table> TablesFromViewModelCollector { get { return TableData.Tables; } }
        Table selectedTable;
        public Table SelectedTable
        {
            get { return selectedTable; }
            set
            {
                if(SelectedTable != value)
                {
                    selectedTable = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if(handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

So I added button under the Picker as you see. And what I am trying to achieve, when the Picker is selected and button is clicked, goes to the page of TableDetails. In this page, I want to show the data of selectedTable. Basically, here is my view for TableDetails:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout Margin="20">
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedTable.Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

And here is my controller:

```
public partial class TableDetails : ContentPage
    {
        public TableDetails()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new TableViewModel();
        }
    }
```

But I dont get the value of the selectedTable.

Comment: what part do you not understand how to do?  Navigate to a page?  Or how to determine which page to navigate to?   How does `Table` map to a specific page?

Comment: Could you please have a look, I edited my answer and I hope I am more clear.

Comment: do you just want to pass the `SelectedTable` to `TableDetails`?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

just pass the value on the constructor

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new TableDetails(VM.SelectedTable));
```

then modify the page constructor

```
public TableDetails(Table selected)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new TableViewModel();
    }
```

Comment: Whats VM in this case? and also where do you use this 'Table selected'?

Comment: `VM` is a reference to your `ViewModel`.  In order to pass a value via constructor, you need to define a parameter in the constructor.  This is basic C#.

Comment: but you dont use selected in anywhere, thats why I am confused

Comment: because this is **YOUR** code, not mine, and I have no idea what you want to do with the value you pass into the page.  You can do whatever you need to with it.